# jquery div content not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ListUsers=function(em){
            var emid = em.title;
            $('.userslistdiv').text('id-' + emid);
            $('.userslistdiv').show;
            //alert("it worked-" + emid);
        };
    });

</script>

<div id="userslistdiv">xxxxxxxxx</div>
```

I'm not getting the changes to the div content.  I get the alert if I uncomment it.  I changed .show to .hide (since the div initially shows) and it does not "hide".

Comment: your selector showing a class, not an ID

Comment: I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: `$('#userslistdiv').text('id-' + emid).show();` make your code clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an id for the div, so need to use [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)(prefix `#`) not [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)(prefix `.`), also `show` is a method so you need to invoke it(add `()` at the end)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ListUsers=function(em){
        var emid = em.title;
        $('#userslistdiv').text('id-' + emid);
        $('#userslistdiv').show();
        //alert("it worked-" + emid);

        // both these can be combined to
        //$('#userslistdiv').text('id-' + emid).show()
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ListUsers=function(em){
            var emid = em.title;
            $('#userslistdiv').text('id-' + emid);
            //$('#userslistdiv').show();
            //alert("it worked-" + emid);
        };
    });

</script>

<div id="userslistdiv">xxxxxxxxx</div>
```

For id use `#` for class use `.`.

Also, don't use show() unless the div is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('.userslistdiv').show;` to `$('.userslistdiv').show();`  Add the parentheses.

Also, the DIV has an ID that's "userslistdiv"

Your code

```
$('.userslistdiv').text('id-' + emid);
$('.userslistdiv').show;
```

is attempting to find the class name.

Use this instead:

```
$('#userslistdiv').text('id-' + emid);
$('#userslistdiv').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the element by id, not class, so

```
$('.userslistdiv')
```

should be

```
$('#userslistdiv')
```

and unrelated to the question, but please put a "var" in front of the variable when declaring it.  This keeps it from polluting the global namespace.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userslistdiv').text('it worked!');
});
```